# string replace in phpmyadmin while keeping inner text

Tags: mysql, replace, phpmyadmin

i need to change quite some html entries in a mysql database. my problem is that some tags need to be replaced while the surrounded code needs to stay the same. in detail: all td-tags in tr-tags with the class "kopf" need to be changed to th-tags (and the addording closing for the tags)

it would not be a problem without the closing tags..

```
update `tt_content` set `bodytext` = replace(`bodytext`,'<tr class="kopf"><td colspan="2">','<tr><th colspan="2">');
```

this would work

from what i found the %-sign is used, but how exactly?:

```
update `tt_content` set `bodytext` = replace(`bodytext`,'<tr class="kopf"><td colspan="2">%</td></tr>','<tr><th colspan="2">%</th></tr>');
```

i guess this would replace all the code within the old td tags by a %-sign?? how can i achive the needed replacement?

**edit:** just to clarify things here is a possible entry in the db:

```
<table class="techDat"  > <tbody> <tr class="kopf"> <td colspan="2"> <p><strong>Technical data:</strong></p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <p>Operating time depending on battery chargeBetriebszeit je Akkuladung</p> </td> <td> <p>Approx. 4 h</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <p>Maximum volume</p> </td> <td> <p>Approx. 120 dB(A)</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <p>Weight</p> </td> <td> <p>Approx. 59 g</p> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

after the mysql replacement it should look like

```
<table class="techDat"  > <tbody> <tr> <th colspan="2"> <p><strong>Technical data:</strong></p> </th> </tr> <tr> <td> <p>Operating time depending on battery chargeBetriebszeit je Akkuladung</p> </td> <td> <p>Approx. 4 h</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <p>Maximum volume</p> </td> <td> <p>Approx. 120 dB(A)</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <p>Weight</p> </td> <td> <p>Approx. 59 g</p> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try two replaces

```
update `tt_content` set `bodytext` = 
replace(replace(`bodytext`,
'<tr class="kopf"><td colspan="2">','<tr><th colspan="2">'),
'</td></tr>','</th></tr>')
```

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't work in my case, since there are other table rows which need to be <tr><td></td></tr>

using the double replace changes every </td></tr> to </th></tr> which is not what i need. i need only to affect the rows with the class="kopf"

Comment: so add 'where bodytext like "%tr class=\"kopf\"%"'

Comment: the % will not work in a replace, you nee dto build your own proper string function for each case

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your records with two queries :

1) for without % sign:
`update`tt_content`set`bodytext`= replace(`bodytext`,'<tr class="kopf"><td colspan="2">','<tr><th colspan="2">');`

2) for  % sign

`update`tt_content`set`bodytext`= replace(`bodytext`,'<tr class="kopf"><td colspan="2">%</td></tr>','<tr><th colspan="2">%</th></tr>')
 where instr(bodytext,'%') > 0` ;

Comment: i guess i described it wrong. there are no %-signs to be searched for. i thought that % sign is used in mysql for whatever other text there is. like the * with filenames...

Comment: Just a doubt why don't you simply try replace("<td ","<th") and replace(class="kopf","")

Comment: because there still need to be normal <td> ... </td> parts. if it was so general there would be no problem. the problem is changing the code like shown in my first post, i edited it to give a bit more detail on this...